# PHP - File Uploading in IE 9 - Windows 7

Tags: php, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

Below is my code for **uploading the file with php in IE 9 - Windows 7**

Having issue related to file uploading process - same code works in other browser

**Test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="uploader.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Uploader.php**

```
<?php

if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ) { print_r($_FILES); copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "/var/www/html/php/uf" ) or die( "Could not copy file!");

} else { die("No file specified!"); } ?>
```

Comment: What are you seeing when you try? The "No file specified!" error?

Comment: Change drive/directory if your are using Windows Installed Drive. Give full permissions to the Upload Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

When a file has been upload on the server , it's real path is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` , NOT `$_FILES['file']['name']` , and DO NOT use the `copy()` , use `move_uploaded_file` , more safe

```
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES)) { 

      if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $new_name = "/var/www/html/php/uf/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
            if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_name)){
                 exit('Could not move the file');
            }

      }else{
           exit('not uploaded file');
      }
      //copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "/var/www/html/php/uf" ) or die( "Could not copy file!");
      //DO NOT use copy for uploaded file , it's unsafe.

} else { 
   exit("No file specified!");
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why is `move_uploaded_file` more safe than `copy`? Just curious, as I haven't heard that before.

Comment: @Vulcan If the first param is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. if use copy() , it will not check for this , just copy and overwrite the destination . if will set the first param as "/etc/passwd" , When I visit this uploaded file , I can get the source of /etc/passwd

Comment: Thanks, I never realized that before.  I think I might need to go update some of my code :p